# Solving a system of equations with constraints on the values we want to find

Tags: systems-of-equations, constraints

In one paper I find these set of equations:

$$ u_1 = b( \omega_1^2 +  \omega_2^2 + \omega_3^2 + \omega_4^2)$$
$$ u_2 = b(\omega_1^2 + \omega_2^2 - \omega_3^2 - \omega_4^2)$$
$$ u_3 = b(\omega_1^2 - \omega_2^2 + \omega_3^2 - \omega_4^2)$$
$$ u_4 = b(\omega_1^2 - \omega_2^2 - \omega_3^2 + \omega_4^2) $$

Where we put numerical values in $\omega_i$ and $\omega_i>0$ (the constraint is based on physical meaning) and you can obtain $u_i$ solving these equations.

But my objective is the inverse, I would like to give values to $u_i$ and obtain $\omega_i$. The problem is that I don't know the range or the specific values I need in $u_i$ to obtain meaningful (physically plausible) values of $\omega_i$ ($\omega_i>0$).

How could I calculate these values using Mathematica? Is there a library of python that I can use? Up until now I have seen examples of $Y=AX$ and obtain $Y$ with constraints in $X$, not obtain $Y$ with constraints in $Y$.

---edit: possible solution---

I don't know why I thought it was a harder problem. At least in Mathematica software is straight forward. The steps I follow was convert to matrix form ($U=AW$), inverse matrix to get $W=A^{-1}U$ and in the equations also write $w_i>0$ conditions ([wolfram alpha solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bx%5E2+%3D%3D+u1%2Bu2%2Bu3%2Bu4+%26%26+y%5E2+%3D%3D+u1%2Bu2-u3-u4+%26%26+z%5E2%3D%3Du1-u2%2Bu3-u4+%26%26+t%5E2%3D%3Du1-u2-u3%2Bu4+%26%26+x%3E0+%26%26+y%3E0+%26%26z%3E0%26%26t%3E0%2C+%5Bx%2Cy%2Cz%2Ct%5D%5D)) (In the link I used $x,y,z,t$ instead of $\omega_i$).

The only problem now is to know numerically for a range of $\omega_i$ what range I have in $u_i$. But as seen in the solution, is not quite easy, it depends on the relations between different $u_i$.

Comment: Note that the $u_i$ are the Hadamart transform of the $b \omega_i^2$. This helps calculating the inverse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$v_i=\frac {u_i}b \qquad \text{and}\qquad x_i=\omega_i^2$$ and you face four linear equations for four unknowns.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand your answer. In this case how you assure that your $x_i$ is not imaginary? or that $\omega_i^2>0$? The problem is that some numerical solutions I try are correct with those equations, but are not physically meaningful (constraints).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $u_i$ are almost the Hadamard transform of the $b \omega_i^2$.

If $H_2$ is the Hadamard transform of size $4$, then

$$(u_1,u_3, u_2,u_4)^t = 2 H_2 \, (b\omega_1^2, b\omega_2^2, b\omega_3^2, b\omega_4^2)^t$$

Then

$$(\omega_1^2, \omega_2^2, \omega_3^2, \omega_4^2)^t = \frac{1}{4b} H_2 \,(u_1,u_3, u_2,u_4)^t$$

Comment: Oh true, I calculated the inverse without realizing that it had the same form. Quite interesting to get faster algorithms.

Comment: I guess you know that there exists a O(n logn) simple fast algorithm for multiplication by Hadamard matrices